# Load .dll library as a Microsoft Service

Tags: c++, service, dllimport

I am writing a Microsoft Service in C++. This service should dynamically load at runtime a .dll library located in a subfolder in the same folder as the executable. However, as someone told me, the actual working directory of the service is not the same as the executable directory, therefore the library is not found and not loaded.
As proof of this fact, I am able to load the library if I start the service executable as an application.

The folder structure of the application is as follows:

```
FOLDER\Service.exe
FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\library.dll
```

How would you access it as a service?

Comment: You can extract the directory from the current module path. You can use GetModuleFileName to retrieve the file path of the current executable

Comment: Thank you Asesh, this works. If you write it as an answer I will gladly accept it!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the directory from the current module path. You can use GetModuleFileName to retrieve file path of the current executable